# Google sheets query returns "loading..."

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I've put together a web application that relies on a series of Google components.

- Google Forms collects data from users
- Google sheets saves the data (automatically)
- Additional "calculated" columns get populated based on data collected from the forms
- I query the "calculated" columns and display the results on a webpage (intranet) using a Table from the Google Visualizations api.

### The problem

The query ***sometimes*** returns the message "loading..." for one of the calculated columns instead of the calculated value. This particular column is unique in that it calls a custom function that I have defined for the spreadsheet. Refreshing the page seems to correct this problem (and the calculated value is displayed), but the "loading..." appears roughly 1 out 3 times that I make a unique visit to the page.

### Looking for

I'm hoping that I can stop this from happening or at least minimize the occurrences. My first thought is to put a delay in the javascript somewhere to give the calculation a longer time to complete, but I'm not sure how. Can you show me? Any help is appreciated.

### Code pieces

#### Google Sheets Formula for that column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(English_Merged_Data!A2:A ="","","<strong><a target='_blank' href='https://docs.google.com/forms/d/.../viewform?entry.500003066="&encode(English_Merged_Data!Q2:Q)&"'>Apply</a></strong>"))
```

#### Encode custom function (in Sheets)

```
//This function encodes a single string or an array of strings
function encode(value) {
  if( typeof value === 'string' ) {
    return encodeURIComponent(value);
  }

  var encodedArray = [];
  for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){
    encodedArray.push(encodeURIComponent(value[i]).replace("'","%27"));
  }
  return encodedArray;
}
```

#### Javascript to display table

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['table']});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
      var query = new google.visualization.Query(
          'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/.../edit?sheet=English_Display_Table'); 
      query.setQuery("select A, B, C, D, F, H, G where A <> '' and not I contains 'Close' and J > toDate(now()) label A 'Mission', B 'Category', C 'Language', D 'Location', F 'Time Commitment', G 'For more details', H 'Apply!'");
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false, allowHtml: true});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can insert a delay with [Utilities.sleep(...)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)). Other than that, it'd be nice to have a minimal self-contained example for reproducing the error; e.g., the data visualization script is probably unnecessary if the "loading" message appears at an earlier stage of processing.

Comment: Try changing `English_Merged_Data!A2:A` and `English_Merged_Data!Q2:Q` by a smaller ranges. If the size is variable use offset() with another function to calculate the number of required rows. Consider to share a file with representative data.

Comment: I've played with the ranges as @Rubén suggests, and I can see that the custom function call is just REALLY slow, even for a single cell.

@NormalHuman you're right, this does appear to be a much simpler problem. Here's a minimal example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6THYnP4ArXVM7objB1C63hxVlvdUZjqwCYKkcpQkOI/edit?usp=sharing

When I copy/paste A1 into new cells, it takes a couple seconds before the "loading..." goes away and is replaced by the result.

Is there any way to speed it up? If not I'll try the `Utilities.sleep()`

Comment: @grayob: Please consider to update your question or to post a new one in order to remove all the unnecessary details and to add those that are important.

Comment: If you want to perform the same action on many cells with a script, don't do it cell-by-cell. Have one script process the entire range. It will not be a custom formula anymore, just a script invoked manually, e.g., from a menu. And I second Rubén's request.

Comment: Instead of a custom function, you can use `REGEXREPLACE` to achieve the same substitution that your custom function does. This can be applied to the entire column with `ARRAYFORMULA`, so the whole thing could be done with `ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(A2:A , "'", "%27"))`

Comment: I've been getting this, too. It's messing up my system and triggering annoying emails saying my values have changed :/